# How to fetch and display data from db inside a common layout file and to display on all views in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, layout, laravel-5

Im new to laravel and im doing a study project in laravel 5.2. I had created a web template, various pages and given their routes, created corresponding controllers and models required to display the webpages. The datas on each of the webpages is fetched from the database. Upto this part its working fine. Right now the logo and some header information in the website is hard-coded inside header.blade.php which i stored inside views/includes folder and it is called from the view/layouts folder via default.blade.php and fetching data on each page as @extends('layouts.default'). I want to fetch that header data also from database and it has to be shown on all the webpages.

Below given is my header.blade.php file code:

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="zerogrid" align="center" style="padding-bottom:2px; padding-top:2px;">
        <ul class="number f-left">
            <li class="mail"><p><a href="mailto:email-comes-from-db-here"><font color="#FFFFFF">email-number-comes-from-db-here</font></a></p></li>
            <li class="phone"><p><a href="tel:phone-number-comes-from-db-here"><font color="#FFFFFF">phone-number-comes-from-db-here</font></a></p></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="top-social f-right" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
            <li><a href="https://facebook.com/page-name-comes-from-db-here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/page-name-comes-from-db-here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/page-name-comes-from-db-here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://linkedin.com/page-name-comes-from-db-here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://youtube.com/page-name-comes-from-db-here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://website-name-comes-from-db-here" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="zerogrid">
        <center><div class="logo"><img src="{{ asset('assets/images/logo-image-name-comes-from-db-here') }}"></div></center>
    </div>
<div class="site-title">
    <div class="zerogrid">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="t-center">Slogan comes from db here</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below given is my routes file code(routes.php):

```
Route::get('/', 'GuestController@home');
Route::get('aboutus', 'GuestController@aboutus');
Route::get('services', 'GuestController@services');
```

Below given is my controller file code(GuestController.php):

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
class GuestController extends Controller
{
    public function home() {
        return view('guest.home');
    }   
    public function aboutus() {
        $result=DB::table('contents')->where('menuname','aboutus')->get();
        return view('guest.aboutus')->with('data',$result);
    }
    public function services() {
        $result=DB::table('contents')->where('menuname','services')->get();
        return view('guest.services')->with('data',$result);
    }
}
```

For displaying each webpage data from db table on a single webpage is already done via routes. But to display the same header data from db to all my pages, what modification in routes/controller files i have to do? Please help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: How did you store the header data in your DB?

Comment: just in a single table named 'headers' and fields such as email, phone, facebook, google, twitter, youtube, website, logo, slogan

Comment: You should provide more information about your DB table structure, actually tell what you get from table when you query the table for fetching the data you want.

Comment: What those fields such as facebook, google etc contain, have you saved links?

Comment: ya. example data will be something like email->abc@gmail.com, phone->+123456789, facebook->http://facebook.com/abc, twitter->http://twitter.com/abc,... logo->logo.png, slogan->some text here..

Comment: see my header.blade.php code given here. In the place where i had given "page-name-comes-from-db-here", it has to fetch the related data from headers table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104110/discussion-between-mahesh-a-r-and-the-alpha).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [view ccomposer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers), for example:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {

        // Using Closure based composers
        view()->composer('guest.includes.header', function ($view) {
            $headerData = \DB::table('headers')->where('...')->get();
            $view->headerData = $headerData;
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Add this provider in the `providers` array in the `config\app.php` file and in the `header.blade.php` you will get a `$headerData` variable whenever the `guest.includes.header` view is loaded/composed so access that variable and loop it and print the data you get from your `DB`. For example:

```
// guest/includes/header.blade.php
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{$headerData['facebook']}}" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

    <!-- You may add more li here-->
</ul>
```

Also, it' possible to do a loop like:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($headesData as $fieldName => $fieldValue)
        {{-- $fieldName will help to determine the icons: facebook/google --}} 
        <li><a href="{{$fieldValue}}"></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This may not provide direct answer to your question because you didn't clerified every bit but anyways, it'll give you the right direction.

Comment: Thank you :) I think your method will also work. While studying abt ur suggestion of using view composer, i found another method which seems little bit simple to implement. I just given   `$result=DB::table('headers')->get();
return view::share('headerdata',$result);` in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php under boot() function & used `use View;` and `use DB;` on the same file. Then i looped the $headerdata variable inside header.blade.php and It displayed the data perfectly as per my requirement. But what is the difference between  between Share() & view composer. Which one is better method?

Comment: Welcome @MaheshAR. View `share` shares the data to every view but composer binds it to a single/multiple view you specify, you may use `share` for this simple task tho :-)